# How to check if a google meet is open/available to join (Python)

Tags: python, google-meet

I want to make a python program that can check if a google meet is open/available to join (like doing ping meet.google.com/custom-meeting-link from cmd).
Is there any modules I could use/any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ping method works you can use that (even if not in native python)

```
import subprocess

ret = subprocess.run(["ping", "https://meet.google.com/custom-meeting-link"])
```

And then check `ret`.

EDIT: A different method is to requests the page and parse it. Keeping it simple, you can just check the title of the page (here using `bs4`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("meet.google.com/custom-meeting-link")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
titlestring = soup.find('title').text

# If title string contains the title of the error page, there's no meeting, else it is online
```

I checked if it was possible to infer the meeting status just from the `requests.get()` response but it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: I can't ping meet.google.com/custom-meeting-link. I get the error `Ping request could not find host meet.google.com/custom-meeting-link. Please check the name and try again.` I can ping the url "meet.google.com" though, just not with a custom meeting link after. (I can't ping the meet from python or cmd).

Comment: I edited the answer with an alternative method

Comment: That looks like a good solution but it is getting an error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 310, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()`

The url's I tried were:
1. https://meet.google.com/lookup/custom-meeting-link
2. meet.google.com/lookup/custom-meeting-link

(I also tried without the /lookup/)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add .text in beautifulsoup call. Check it now

Comment: That sort of works. I have printed title string but I always get the output "Meet", even if it is closed or it doesn't exist.

I used "https://meet.google.com/eek-sdh-etw" as a test (it doesn't exist) but I still get the output "Meet"

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with Google Meet before, but you can probably detect if a Google meet is open with their API

[Google Meet API's documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/meet)

Comment: I have looked at this before but I can't see a way to check if a specific meet is open.